# is It possible to reject a jquery Deferred within pipe

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

Is it possible to reject a Deferred within pipe ?

I am trying to do it like this :

```
function doPostStuff(sentData){
        return $.post("postStuff.foo", sentData)
        .pipe(function(returnedData){
            if (returnedData.justDoIt != "YEAH BABY oO") {
                return $.Deferred().reject('Error posting stuff', returnedData);
            }
            var finalData = transformResults(returnedData);
            return finalData;
        });  
    }
```

and then calling like this :

```
doPostStuff(someData)
    .done(function(finalData){
        alert("you are here ! ");
    })
    .fail(function(message, failData){
        alert(message);
    });
```

But for some reason i never reach the fail() .

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thank you !

EDIT.

So my code was not wrong after all it was a server side issue.

Just to prove my point and demonstrating that the request is still async despite what is prentended by the people who answered below ( who obviously did not read the documentation of Deferred in details before answering ) :

```
doDeferredTest : function(){
    return $.post("doMiniTest.foo")
        .pipe(function(erb){
            console.error("inside pipe at " + Date());
            if(erb.status != 'SUCCESS'){
                return $.Deferred().reject('Error posting stuff', erb);
            }
            return erb;
    });
},



    var done = false;
    console.error("triggereing Do deffered test at " + Date()); 
    doDeferredTest().done(function(){
        done = true;
        console.error("inside done at " + Date());  
    })
    .fail(function(){
        console.error("failed at " + Date());

    });
    console.error("after doDeferredTest triggered " + Date() + " done = " + done);
```

If you delay the server response you should see in the console that the request is indeed async and that the fail triggers correctly from within pipe. And contrary to what was prentended below there is no need for an intermediary deffered object since $.post returns a promise that you can chain with other deffered methods.

Comment: But you are returning the promise interface from doPostStuff(), not the deferred object. Anyway, ajax is async

Comment: `jQuery.postJSON? ` jQuery  come with one built-in function.?

Comment: changed it to $.post for clarity but the same problem applies

Comment: @A.Wolff of course it is async. What woul make my code not being async ? Why the downvote ??

Comment: @A.Wolff obviously I do.

Comment: thank you for that link. You should probably read the 'Use deferred objects / promises' paragraph to understand why you dont need to create a dev variable.

Comment: @A.Wolff have you tried mine ? You will notice that it works and is async contrary to what you pretend.

Comment: You should post your edit as answer then. But again: "You will notice that it works and is async contrary to what you pretend." I've never pretended the opposite, where did I???

Comment: Sure you can play on the words after deleting most of your comments and your downvoted answer ...

Comment: @azpublic the only thing i said regarding async behaviour was: `Anyway, ajax is async` in first non deleted comment. Which btw means the opposite of how you seem to understand it. But again, my bad, your code was correct using pipe()